# How to create a testlink platform when using br.eti.kinoshita.testlinkjavaapi

Tags: java, api, platform, testlink

I am trying to create an entire project on Testlink using the [br.eti.kinoshita.testlinkjavaapi](https://jar-download.com/java-documentation-javadoc.php?a=testlink-java-api&g=br.eti.kinoshita&v=1.9.2-1) library.

The only thing I didn't manage to do is to create a new Platform.

I tried:
`api=new TestLinkAPI(new URL("http://"localhost/testlink/lib/api/xmlrpc/v1/xmlrpc.php),devKey);

//where devKey was taken from my testlink environment

```
Platform platform=new Platform(1,platformName,platformDescription);

api.addPlatformToTestPlan(projectId, testPlanId, platformName);

//projectId and testPlanId are directly taken from testlink and are both integer

//platformDescription is a String which looks like "a simple description"

// the "1" corresponds to the ID I want to give to my platform (I put 1 because none ID is already present on my project)
```

`

But this code is not efficient, and I get the error:

> platformName does not exists.

I think the problem is that I have to first add the platform to the project but I can't find any method to do that...

Do you have any idea?

Comment: how is platformName initialized?

Comment: platformName=new String("my_name_of_platform")

Comment: i mean, what are your objects ? which class ? how are parameters declared/initialized?  what is `api`? We need a bit more context to help...

Comment: Sorry, I added few information on my question. Thank you for your insterest